# Как вытащить результат из запроса MySql в php

Tags: php, mysql

В запросе такого типа:

```
$queryLoginCheck = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
    $resultLogin = $db->query($queryLoginCheck);
```

Я делал это так:

```
$rowLogin = $resultLogin->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Как сделать то же самое в таком запросе

`$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE nick = ?";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param("s", $nickName);
$statement->execute();`

Так?

```
$statment->execute();
$statement->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in /home/u846159811/public_html/signupuser.php:35

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in /home/u846159811/public_html/signupuser.php:35
```

Comment: точно так же, после execute, если ошибок не было, вызываете fetch на $statement

Comment: обновил. так???

Comment: Да, если не считать что у execute буква у названия переменной пропущена.

Comment: бывает))) ide в помощь)

Comment: ошибку выдает. до добавления строчки после "Success" все робило и выводило "Success"

Comment: но оно же не может просто "не работать" куда то, какую то ошибку писать то должно. если вообще не работает, может что то в синтаксисе не так, посмотрите тогда в error_log веб-сервера, такие ошибки обычно туда пишутся

Comment: @PavelVorobyov что мешает Вам посмотреть документацию ?

Comment: теперь проверьте error, errno - http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-stmt.php

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну значит `$x=$statment->execute(); $x->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: теперь другая. обновил

Comment: есть варианты решения?

Comment: Есть, читайте документацию! Особенно, что возвращают методы при возникновении ошибок.

Answer (score 2):

Вкратце полный код будет выглядеть так:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "table_name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

//кодировка соединения
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

//запрос
$sql = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE sid = ?";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

//входные данные
$d = 45;
$statement->bind_param("i", $d);

//выполнение запроса
if (!$statement->execute()) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить запрос: (" . $statement->errno . ") " . $statement->error;
}

//получаем данные
$res = $statement->get_result();
//выводим результат на экран
var_dump($res->fetch_assoc());
```

Выведет

```
array (size=2)
  'sid' => int 45
  'name' => string 'Пук-пук' (length=14)
```