# Ошибка Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean

Tags: php

Ошибка

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in /home/ifu-institut/public_html/application/modules/core/core.php on line 1103
```

Код:

```
$page_info = $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->row_array() : NULL;
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас `$query` - `false`

Comment: $query = $this->db->get('content', 1); - значит проблема с базой?

Comment: @NataliGrigor может да, а может и нет. Ошибки примерно так обработайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751202/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-mysql-%d0%b2-php/751289#751289

Comment: это код из imagecms, ошибка возникла при переносе на другой хостинг, раньше все работало